# SFDX: force:mdapi:deploy -r to reference a file

Tags: salesforcedx, mdapideploy

Is it possible to reference a file within `force:mdapi:deploy -r` in order to extract the names of the test classes to run?

What I am trying to achieve is something like:

`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -c -d src -w 20 -l RunSpecifiedTests -r ClassesToValidate.txt -u myUser`

I cannot find anything like this within the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do so directly (or, at least, it's not documented, as you've noted).

However, if your shell supports parameter substitution, awk, and other tools (i.e. you have a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-like environment), you can use shell commands, such as:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy ... -r $(cat ClassesToValidate.txt) ...
```

Or...

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy ... -r `cat ClassesToValidate.txt` ...
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that!

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! Beautiful.